# sudo apt-get install swig on Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: 14.04, apt, python

Im' trying to install swig on Ubuntu 14.04:

```
sudo apt-get install swig

Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package swig
```

Seach gives something irrelevant:

```
apt-cache search swig

python-sip - Python/C++ bindings generator runtime library
libkml0 - Library to manipulate KML 2.2 OGC standard files
libapparmor-perl - AppArmor library Perl bindings
```

Howewer [here](http://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=swig&searchon=names&suite=precise&section=all)

So what is the proper way to install swig?

**Update:**
Seems `sudo apt-get update` helped.

Comment: What is the contents of your `sources.list` ?

Comment: You may need to [enable the `universe` repository](http://askubuntu.com/questions/148638/how-do-i-enable-the-universe-repository)

Answer (score 7):

download the latest development (master) version of SWIG:

```
git clone https://github.com/swig/swig.git

cd swig
sudo apt-get install automake
./autogen.sh
./configure
sudo apt-get install bison flex
make
sudo make install
```

Hope it helps,
Gepp

Comment: I followed this, but it doesn't seem like swig was installed. When running `swig -version`, I get `-bash: /usr/bin/swig: No such file or directory`.